# List of all frames on a page

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I am working on  a problem where I need to enter data into a form in a iFrame.

The problem is that the iframe does not have an ID or name.  It is the 
first iframe (or frame) on the page, so I was planning to get a list 
of the frames on the page and select the first one in the returned 
list.  I have done something simliar with windows 
ie:

**order_window = page.driver.browser.window_handles[0]
page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(order_window)**

can something similar be done with frames? 
if so how?

cucumber (1.0.6)
Capybara (1.1.1) 
selenium-webdriver (2.5.0)